# Alternative to "subclassing" structs in C

Tags: c, sockets, struct

I've heard that when the BSD socket libraries were being designed, C programming lacked a certain pattern or feature that led to the design we have today.

For example, a `struct socketaddr_in` is cast to a `struct socketaddr` when passed to system calls such as `bind`.

From GNU libc header files:

```
/* POSIX.1g specifies this type name for the `sa_family' member.  */
    typedef unsigned short int sa_family_t;

/* This macro is used to declare the initial common members
   of the data types used for socket addresses, `struct sockaddr',
   `struct sockaddr_in', `struct sockaddr_un', etc.  */

#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON(sa_prefix) \
  sa_family_t sa_prefix##family

#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON_SIZE  (sizeof (unsigned short int))

/* Structure describing a generic socket address.  */
struct sockaddr
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sa_);    /* Common data: address family and length.  */
    char sa_data[14];       /* Address data.  */
  };

/* Structure describing an Internet socket address.  */
struct sockaddr_in
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sin_);
    in_port_t sin_port;         /* Port number.  */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;        /* Internet address.  */

    /* Pad to size of `struct sockaddr'.  */
    unsigned char sin_zero[sizeof (struct sockaddr) -
               __SOCKADDR_COMMON_SIZE -
               sizeof (in_port_t) -
               sizeof (struct in_addr)];
  };

/* Internet address.  */
typedef uint32_t in_addr_t;
struct in_addr
  {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
  };
```

An example program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...

    // Initialize the server address
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr = (struct sockaddr_in) {
        .sin_port = htons(port),
        .sin_family = AF_INET ,
        .sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY
    };

    // Bind the server address to the TCP/IP socket
    int status = bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    ...
}
```

I can't think of how else this generic interface could be put in place. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence? How/why it works? Why they would do it? The underlying details of how else one might implement a similar subclassing scheme?

Comment: I mean, this looks like the most elegant way to do it (see my "example program"). I remember one of my professors noting a few years ago that there's another way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that C lacked the subclassing pattern when the BSD socket libraries were being designed. On the contrary, the BSD socket API designers specifically took advantage of this pattern. Casting structs to base structs (more generic structs with fewer fields) and back to specialized structs is very common and fully supported. C even has some guarantees to make sure it works portably: if the first element of a struct definition is another struct, C guarantees that the type, memory address and layout of the first member of the enclosing struct is the same as the type, memory address and layout of the enclosing struct cast to the type of its first member.

Comment: The delegate pattern in Monkey's answer is interesting, and I've always wondered if it appears in production code.

However, I agree with you that this notion of casting structs is legitimate as it is enforced by struct alignment rules by the C standard.

Comment: @OregonTrail yes, it absolutely does! The poster child for this pattern is the the VFS switch in almost every operating system kernel (the thing that takes generic file operations like "open" and "delete" and delegates them to actual filesystem implementations). Here's part of the definitions for the Linux version: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9.5/include/linux/fs.h#L1515

Answer (score 3):

You can use a delegate pattern to support a form of inheritance in C. It looks pretty, it's generic but it's quite heavy-weight : got quite a few potential failure points, requires some heap allocation, etc. I guess they did not want to have this kind of weight for an OS API ?

Here's an example of this

```
struct ShapeDelegate {
  double (*getSurfaceArea)(void* data);
  int (*isInside)(void* data, double x, double y);
  void (*destroy)(void* data);
}

struct Shape {
  void* data;
  struct ShapeDelegate delegate;
}

double Shape_getSurfaceArea(Shape* self) {
  return self->delegate.getSurfaceArea(self->data);
}

int Shape_isInside(Shape* self, double x, double y) {
  return self->delegate.isInside(self->data, x, y);
}

void Shape_destroy(Shape* self) {
  if (self->delegate.destroy != NULL)
    self->delegate.destroy(self->data);
}
```

Now, say, you want a Circle as implementation of Shape

```
struct CircleData {
  double x, y, r;
}

double Circle_getSurfaceArea(void* data) {
  CircleData* self = (CircleData*)data;
  return 2 * M_PI * self->r * self->r;
}

int Circle_isInside(void* data, double x, double y) {
  double dist;
  CircleData* self = (CircleData*)data;
  dist = sqrt(sqr(x - self->x) + sqr(y - self->y)); 
  return dist < self->r;
}

void Circle_destroy(void* data) {
  free(data);
}

struct ShapeDelegate Circle_ShapeDelegate {
   Circle_getSurfaceArea,
   Circle_isInside,
   Circle_destroy
};
```

You need some sort of constructor

```
void
Shape_initAsCircle(Shape* self, double x, double y, double r) {
  CircleData* data;

  data = (CircleData*)malloc(sizeof(CircleData));
  data->x = x, data->y = y, data->r = r;

  self->data = data;
  self.delegate = Circle_ShapeDelegate;
}
```